# How to add an issue trackers(Bag,Feature,Support) to existing project?

Tags: c#, redmine-plugins, redmine-api

How to add an issue trackers(Bag, Feature, Support) to the existing project?

Please, help to solve

```
    [enter image description here][1]var project = manager.GetObject(project_id, null);
    project.Description = "Updated description";
    ProjectIssueCategory proCat = new ProjectIssueCategory();
    proCat.Id = 10;
    proCat.Name = "Feature";
    project.IssueCategories = new List();
    project.IssueCategories.Add(proCat);
    project.Trackers = new List();

    project.Trackers.Add(new ProjectTracker(){Name = "Bag"});
    manager.UpdateObject(project_id, project);
    var updatedProject = manager.GetObject<Project>(project_id, null);
    Console.WriteLine("Updated issue: {0}.", updatedProject);
```

Comment: this code doesn't add the task trackers